# SignalR self hosting with owin

Tags: signalr, owin

I want to create an signalr app that will be self hosted using Owin, so to start off i tried to run the sample that is on https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Self-host. But when i run the application and then navigate to /signar/hubs i get a 500 Server error. I get the same exception when i try to connect from my client app.

Do i need to add something else apart from what is in the sample code? or does anyone know of a good tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

Things to check if trying to access from an external connection:

Are you hosting the server on all addresses or just localhost?

```
// use http://*:8080 to bind to all addresses. 
string url = "http://localhost:8080";
```

Make sure to run app as administrator.

Also, is the Windows firewall blocking the port you are using? I had to add an exception to allow incoming TCP connections on that port.

Comment: Yeah i've already done what you said. The problem was that i didn't add the Console.ReadLine(); so the service was terminated. In any case, thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah, ok glad you got it going.